# CoreML can't work in concurrency (Multithreading)?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency, coreml

Despite my best efforts to make `CoreML MLModel` process its predictions in parallel, seems like under-the-hood Apple forcing it to run in a serial/one-by-one manner.

I made a public repository reproducing the PoC of the issue:
https://github.com/SocialKitLtd/coreml-concurrency-issue.

**What I have tried:**

- Re-create the `MLModel` every time instead of a global instance
- Use only `.cpuAndGpu` configuration

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I'm trying to utilize multithreading to process a bunch of video frames at the same time (assuming the CPU/RAM can take it) faster than the one-by-one strategy.

Code (Also presented in the repository):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let parallelTaskCount = 3
        
        for i in 0...parallelTaskCount - 1 {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!
                self.runPrediction(index: i, image: image)
            }
        }
    }

    
    func runPrediction(index: Int, image: UIImage) {
        let conf = MLModelConfiguration()
        conf.computeUnits = .cpuAndGPU
        conf.allowLowPrecisionAccumulationOnGPU = true
        
        let myModel = try! MyModel(configuration: conf)
        let myModelInput = try! MyModelInput(LR_inputWith: image.cgImage!)
        // Prediction
        let predicition = try! myModel.prediction(input: myModelInput)
        print("finished proccessing \(index)")
    }
    
}
```

**Any help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: I’m not at all surprised that you might not be able to do CoreML predictions in parallel (as I would assume it is already attempting maximum parallelism already), but I’ll play around with it this weekend.

Comment: Regarding constrained parallelism of synchronous work, I would use `concurrentPerform` if using GCD, or operation queue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` or async-await’s cooperative thread pool. In this case, `parallelTaskCount` is 3 so it doesn’t matter, but just doing a whole series of dispatches to global queue is not a good idea if the count was higher. But none of this is relevant to the question at hand, which is running multiple CoreML predictions in parallel.

Comment: Hey @Rob, thanks for the response. I agree with the second comment, I actually made a full multi-threaded approach which works when I'm not using CoreML, I just made a PoC that I think it's the same in terms of parallelism. Really hope this is solvable as we counted on this to work in parallel for a new major release, thank you for the constant help my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you employ parallel execution on CPU, you can achieve significant performance gains on CPU-bound calculations only. But CoreML is not a CPU-bound. When you leverage the GPU (e.g., with `.cpuAndGPU`) you will not achieve the same sort of CPU-parallelism-driven performance gains that you will see with CPU-only calculations.

That having said, using the GPU (or the neural engine) is so much faster than the parallelized CPU rendition, as one would generally forgo parallelized CPU calculations, altogether, and favor the GPU rendition. The non-parallel GPU compute rendition will often be faster than a parallelized CPU rendition.

That having been said, when I employed parallelism in GPU-compute tasks, there is still some modest performance gain. In my experiments, I saw minor performance benefits (13 and 18% faster when I went from serial to three concurrent operations on iPhone and M1 iPad, respectively) running GPU-based CoreML calculations, but slightly more material benefits on a Mac. Just do not expect a dramatic performance improvement.

---

Profiling with Instruments (by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> in Xcode or choosing “Product” » “Profile”) can be illuminating. See [Recording Performance Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/recording_performance_data/).

First, let us compare a `computeUnits` of `.cpuOnly` scenario first. Here it is running 20 CoreML `prediction` calls sequentially (with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1):

[image]

And, if I switch to the CPU view, I can see that it is jumping between two performance cores on my iPhone 12 Pro Max:

[image]

That makes sense. OK, now let us change the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `3`, the overall processing time (the `processingAll` function) drops from 5 to 3½ minutes:

[image]

And when I switch to the CPU view, to see what is going on, it looks like it started running on both performance cores in parallel, but switched to some of the efficiency cores (probably because the thermal state of the device was getting stressed, which explains we did not achieve anything close to 2× performance):

[image]

So, when doing CPU-only CoreML calculations, parallel execution can yield significant benefits. That having been said, the CPU-only calculations are much slower than the GPU calculations.

---

When I switched to `.cpuAndGPU`, the difference `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1 vs 3 was far less pronounced, taking 45 seconds when allowing three concurrent operations and 50 seconds when executing serially. Here it is running three in parallel:

[image]

And sequentially:

[image]

But in contrast to the `.cpuOnly` scenarios, you can see in the CPU track, that the CPUs are largely idle. Here is the latter with the CPU view to show the details:

[image]

So, one can see that letting them run on multiple CPUs does not achieve much performance gain as this is not CPU-bound, but is obviously constrained by the GPU.

---

Here is my code for the above. Note, I used `OperationQueue` as it provides a simple mechanism to control the degree of concurrency (the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`:

```swift
import os.log

private let poi = OSLog(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

and

```swift
func processAll() {
    let parallelTaskCount = 20

    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3          // or try `1`

    let id = OSSignpostID(log: poi)
    os_signpost(.begin, log: poi, name: #function, signpostID: id)

    for i in 0 ..< parallelTaskCount {
        queue.addOperation {
            let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!
            self.runPrediction(index: i, image: image, shouldAddContuter: true)
        }
    }

    queue.addBarrierBlock {
        os_signpost(.end, log: poi, name: #function, signpostID: id)
    }
}

func runPrediction(index: Int, image: UIImage, shouldAddContuter: Bool = false) {
    let id = OSSignpostID(log: poi)
    os_signpost(.begin, log: poi, name: #function, signpostID: id, "%d", index)
    defer { os_signpost(.end, log: poi, name: #function, signpostID: id, "%d", index) }

    let conf = MLModelConfiguration()
    conf.computeUnits = .cpuAndGPU                 // contrast to `.cpuOnly`
    conf.allowLowPrecisionAccumulationOnGPU = true
    
    let myModel = try! MyModel(configuration: conf)
    let myModelInput = try! MyModelInput(LR_inputWith: image.cgImage!)
    // Prediction
    let prediction = try! myModel.prediction(input: myModelInput)
    os_signpost(.event, log: poi, name: "finished processing", "%d %@", index, prediction.featureNames)
}
```

---

Note, above I have focused on CPU usage. You can also use the “Core ML” template in Instruments. E.g. here are the Points of Interest and the CoreML tracks next to each other on my M1 iPad Pro (with `maxConcurrencyOperationCount` set to 2 to keep it simple):

[image]

At first glance, it looks like CoreML is processing these in parallel, but if I run it again with `maxConcurrencyOperationCount` of `1` (i.e., serially), the time for those individual compute tasks is shorter, which suggests that in the parallel scenario that there is some GPU-related contention.

Anyway, in short, you can use Instruments to observe what is going on. And one can achieve significant improvements in performance through parallel processing for CPU-bound tasks only, and anything requiring the GPU or neural engine will be further constrained by that hardware.

Comment: Hey @Rob! Thank you for the detailed and interesting answer! I went through it deeply, and in conclusion, in theory, I can utilize the CoreML model to run in parallel only if I use the .cpu configuration (assuming the model is not that slow on CPU only)? What about if we will use 2 different instances of the models and run them with the .cpuAndGpu conf? I wonder if that a good idea.

Comment: Also, do you think it matter (in case of trying to parallelize with .cpu) if we use a global instance of the CoreML model or re-creating an CoreML model for each prediction?

Comment: I was merely making an academic observation that when dealing with CPU-bound calculations, parallelism can yield significant benefits.  But with CoreML, the GPU is so much faster than the CPU rendition, that it probably doesn’t make sense to even consider CPU-only, IMHO.

Comment: But I would still go ahead and use parallelism (esp when CPU has so much idle time while the GPU does its thing), but the gains over the serial rendition are simply going to be more modest than one might have hoped for.